# C++ could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a generic class for logging which

1. can be called as a functor with the string to log
2. enriches the string with some information (system time, log level, ...)
3. passes the log message to an output class which implements the << operator. This "output channel" can be defined upon construction.

The code:

```
template<class Writer>
class Logger
{
public:
Logger(Writer* writer);
~Logger(void);

void operator() (char level, std::string message);

private:
Writer* writer;
};

template<class Writer>
Logger<Writer>::Logger(Writer* writer)
    : writer(writer)
{
}

template<class Writer>
Logger<Writer>::~Logger(void)
{
}

template<class Writer>
void Logger<Writer>::operator ()(char level, std::string message) {

    /* do something fancy with the message */
    /* ... */
    /* then write to output channel */

    this->writer << message;
}
```

However I get the error "Could not deduce template argument" on compilation. The line the error occurs is

```
this->writer << message;
```

I'm pretty new to C++ templates, I'm rather coming from the C#-side of the force... Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You should show how you invoke `Logger<Writer>::operator ()`

Comment: I see no reason to use pointer instead of reference here.

Comment: Yeah you're right, thank you... Just changed it into a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a pointer as the left operand of `operator <<`:

```
this->writer << message;
//    ^^^^^^
```

If you want to use a pointer, you should then do:

```
*(this->writer) << message;
```

Or even better (provided that a `Logger` class must always be associated to a `Writer`, so that the `writer` pointer should never be null), replace the pointer with a reference:

```
template<class Writer>
class Logger
{
public:
    Logger(Writer& writer);
//         ^^^^^^^
    // ...
private:
    Writer& writer;
//  ^^^^^^^
};
```

This will allow you to use your original version of the call operator, and write:

```
this->writer << message;
```

Now all of this of course is correct under the assumption that an appropriate overload of `operator <<` exists.

Comment: @LucTouraille: Perhaps better, yes. I will mention that, thank you

Comment: Thank you, I should have seen that :)